# responsive text sizes using vw

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap and have a hero section with big text and an image. It doesn't seem by default that text is responsive. I have done it with the image using a class of 'img-fluid'.

Regarding the text, I found a really easy way to make the text responsive but it seems like a 'too good to be true' way so could anyone please tell me why it would be a bad idea to do this and what would be a better alternative?

```
h1 {
  font-size: 8vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1><font size="4" color="White" >text, context write </font><h1>
```

You can make any size you want to use HTML tags